# Random Insert into a second table

Tags: mysql, random, insert

I would like to pull 10 random records from a MySql table (questions) and insert them into another table (active), but only records which are not already in the second table (active).
The code I have works if the second table is not empty, but does not give any results at all if the table IS empty. Can anybody see why and what I can do please?

```
INSERT INTO active (quesindex)
(
SELECT DISTINCT(questions.quesindex)
FROM questions,  (
        SELECT questions.quesindex AS sid
        FROM questions, active
where  questions.quesindex NOT IN (SELECT active.quesindex FROM active )  
        ORDER BY RAND( )
        LIMIT 10
    ) tmp
WHERE questions.quesindex = tmp.sid
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing unnecessary cross joins between the `questions` and `active` tables.  This query should do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO active (quesindex)
    SELECT q.quesindex AS sid
    FROM questions q
    where  q.quesindex NOT IN (SELECT a.quesindex FROM active a)  
    ORDER BY RAND( )
    LIMIT 10;
```

This is an alternative version, using `left outer join`:

```
INSERT INTO active (quesindex)
    SELECT q.quesindex AS sid
    FROM questions q left outer join
         active a
         on q.quesindex = a.quesindex
    WHERE a.quesindex is null
    ORDER BY RAND( )
    LIMIT 10;
```

This latter version would work, for instance, when there are `NULL` values in `acive.quesindex`.